# 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

I am coding a program that read data from input file 'payroll.txt'. I have already created the file using notepad. However I am running into an issue When I run the program I get this following error: ****'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.****
I have installed minGW- and configured the PATH in the System environmental variables settings. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22hkl.png)
This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void instructions();

void reportTitle();

void displayEmployeeInfo(string employeeName, double hourlyRate,
    double hoursWorked, double taxRate, double grossAmount,
    double netAmount);

void totalAmounts(double totalGrossAmount, double totalNetAmount);

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string employeeName;
    double hourlyRate, hoursWorked, taxRate, grossAmount, netAmount,
        totalGrossAmount = 0.0, totalNetAmount = 0.0;

    infile.open("payroll.txt");

    if (!infile) {
        cout << "Input failed." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    instructions();
    reportTitle();

    getline(infile, employeeName, '#');
    infile >> hourlyRate >> hoursWorked >> taxRate;
    infile.ignore(100, '\n');

    while (!infile.eof()) {
        grossAmount = hoursWorked * hourlyRate;

        if (hoursWorked > 40)
            grossAmount += (hoursWorked * hourlyRate * .5);

        netAmount = grossAmount - (grossAmount * taxRate / 100);

        totalGrossAmount += grossAmount;

        totalNetAmount += netAmount;

        displayEmployeeInfo(employeeName, hourlyRate, hoursWorked, taxRate,
            grossAmount, netAmount);

        getline(infile, employeeName, '#');
        infile >> hourlyRate >> hoursWorked >> taxRate;
        infile.ignore(100, '\n');
    }

    totalAmounts(totalGrossAmount, totalNetAmount);
    return 0;
}

void instructions()
{
    cout << "This payroll program calculates an individual "
         << "employee pay and\ncompany totals "
         << "using data from a data file payroll.txt. \n"
         << "\n\nA payroll report showing payroll information "
         << "is displayed.\n\n";
}

void reportTitle()
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << left;
    cout << setw(24) << "Employee" << setw(11) << "Hourly"
         << setw(11) << "Hours" << setw(9) << "Tax"
         << setw(11) << "Gross" << setw(10) << "Net" << endl;
    cout << setw(25) << "Name" << setw(9) << "Rate" << setw(12)
         << "Worked" << setw(8) << "Rate" << setw(10) << "Amount"
         << setw(10) << "Amount" << endl
         << endl;
}

void displayEmployeeInfo(string employeeName, double hourlyRate,
    double hoursWorked, double taxRate, double grossAmount,
    double netAmount)

{
    cout << left << setw(25) << employeeName << right << setw(5)
         << hourlyRate << setw(10) << hoursWorked << setw(10) << taxRate
         << setw(10) << grossAmount << setw(10) << netAmount << endl;
}

void totalAmounts(double totalGrossAmount, double totalNetAmount)
{

    cout << left << setw(26) << "\nTotals" << right << setw(35)
         << totalGrossAmount << setw(10) << totalNetAmount << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have Visual Studio Community? It typically uses its built in compiler. Perhaps you have Visual Studio Code? Image clears that right up. Visual Studio Code.

Comment: That error practically means that the system cannot understand what you refer to by 'g++'.Most probably you messed up somewhere setting up your path. If you're using windows, try cd to get to the path of g++ and run.

Comment: Search this site for *not recognized as an internal or external command*. This question has been asked and answered here many times before.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to edit the Visual Studio... out of the title and was rejected because that title already exists. Are you absolutely sure you want to use Visual Studio Code? You may have intended to get community and clicked the wrong link. Visual Studio Community is much, much easier to configure than Visual Studio Code.

Comment: If you do what to use visual Studio Code, you need to edit the question some more. Remove the code, the build process doesn't get that far, and add in the three JSON files you will have had to edit.

Comment: The error message means mingw is either not installed or not in one of the folders of your PATH environment variable. Could also be a misconfiguration of your `tasks.json` and/or `launch.json` meaning wrong path to g++ specified in either of these. Also did you reboot or logout the login after installing mingw? If not your PATH environment variable may not have updated as environment variables propagate from the parent process and don't update for already running processes